# SQL: combine case and number to date conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, date, case

I want to do a sql statement which calculates in one table the substraction of 2 Date values. If the value is negative I just want to show it as the 0 value.

The number value is the number of seconds a payment is in a current state.
I convert it with a trick to a time value(Date type).

My current code is

```
SELECT 
max(CASE WHEN t1.time_event < SYSDATE and t2.time_event > SYSDATE THEN to_char(to_date(max(round(SYSDATE - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60)),'ssssss'),'hh24:mi:ss') else to_char(to_date(0)) END) as "current_age"
from tbl_dummyfeed t1 join tbl_dummyfeed t2 on t1.payment_Id = t2.payment_id
where t1.event = 'accepted' and t2.event = 'enriched');
```

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on `sysdate` and `to_char()` usage

Comment: MAX is an aggregate function, i.e. only one row returned (as long as no GROUP BY.) So why DISTINCT?

Comment: Ok I removed distinct, but I don't think this is the business case.

Comment: Is your 'enriched' time really in the future, not just later that the 'accepted' time? Did you really mean to subtract the accepted time from the current not, rather than its matching enriched time? And when can that calculation be negative?

Comment: Yes it is, because I want to know how many payments are in a specific state at THIS moment. So the next state will always be in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a similar date 'trick', which is to add the fractional-days difference to a nominal date which has the time portion as midnight - you could use a fixed date, or `trunc(sysdate)`, as long as the time ends up as midnight - without having to multiply by 24*60*60. (Your `to_date()` solution does the same thing implicitly, effectively adding the number of seconds to midnight on the first day of the current month; but this might be a little clearer). But you can also move the `case` clauses into the `where` filter

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
  + nvl(max(sysdate - t1.time_event), 0), 'HH24:MI:SS') as "current_age"
from tbl_dummyfeed t1
join tbl_dummyfeed t2
on t1.trax_id = t2.trax_id
where t1.event = 'accepted'
and t1.time_event < sysdate
and t2.event = 'enriched'
and t2.time_event > sysdate;
```

You could also use an analytic approach so you only have to hit the table once, with a subquery that pairs up each 'enriched' time with the previous 'accepted' time for that ID, and which you then filter against the current time:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
  + nvl(max(sysdate - time_accepted), 0), 'HH24:MI:SS') as "current_age"
from (
  select last_value(case when event = 'accepted' then time_event end ignore nulls)
      over (partition by trax_id order by time_event) as time_accepted,
    case when event = 'enriched' then time_event end as time_enriched
  from tbl_dummyfeed
)
where time_accepted < sysdate
and time_enriched > sysdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, only the conversion to time hh24:mi:ss still needs to happen.

```
SELECT max(CASE WHEN t1.time_event < SYSDATE and t2.time_event > SYSDATE THEN round((SYSDATE - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60) else 0 END) as "current_age"
    from tbl_dummyfeed t1 join tbl_dummyfeed t2 on t1.payment_id= t2.payment_id
    where t1.event = 'accepted' and t2.event = 'enriched';
```

When I add the conversion to hh24:mm:ss The solution looks like this

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(max(CASE WHEN t1.time_event < SYSDATE and t2.time_event > SYSDATE THEN round((SYSDATE - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60
* 60) else 0 END),'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss') as "current_age" from tbl_dummyfeed t1 join tbl_dummyfeed t2 on t1.trax_Id = t2.trax_id where t1.event = 'accepted' and t2.event = 'enriched';
```

This is the only good solution for my question. Hope this helps people.